# Возможно ли в синхронном коде для телеграмм бота вызвать асинхронную функцию из другого файла питона?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Возможно ли в синхронном коде для телеграмм бота вызвать асинхронную функцию из другого файла питона?

Пытаюсь реализовать в синхронном коде возможность открытия веб приложения.

Или же как можно реализовать данное мероприятие в самом синхронном коде?

Comment: ничего не мешает вам это сделать насколько я знаю, вам достаточно просто попробовать что бы узнать наверняка

Comment: @videxerion как именно попробовать?

Comment: ну вы хотите узнать можно ли вызвать синк функцию в асинк коде. Попробуйте и вызовите

Comment: @videxerion наоборот — асинк функцию в синк коде

Comment: @videxerion в этом и проблема, как вызвать синх функцию в асних я знаю, но вот как наоборот? Питон выдаёт кучу ошибок на это действие

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run).

Comment: ага, понял вас. Как освобожусь покапаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию `run()` из `asyncio`.

```
import asyncio


async def asink():
    print('Привет, а я асинхронная функция')
    print('И меня только что вызвали внутри синхронной')


def sinck():
    print('Привет, я синхронная функция')
    asyncio.run(asink())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sinck()
```